# How to get an APK file icon

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get an icon of some APK file, but with no success.
The thing is, I have the APK file path and using that, I want to get its icon (as a Drawable).

Thanx upfront.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [PackageItemInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html). With that, you can read out the icon for any app installed on the device!

Or even faster: Use

```
    Context.getPackageManager()
```

to receive a reference on a PackageManager. On that, you can call:

```
    getActivityIcon(Intent i)
```

The only thing you have still to do is packing the package path in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Matthias' answer, since my original assumed `ic_launcher.png`:

```
int icon = 0;

// if you don't know the icon's name:
icon = (new PackageItemInfo()).icon;

// if you do know the icon's name:
icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher; // or whatever your resource id is

Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable( icon );
```